# Python DB async Task Schedule

Tags: python, mysql, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I'm working with telegram-bot and mysql-connector with a MySQL DB to store all user data.

3 times a day I need to run the query:

`UPDATE users SET rolls = rolls + 1 WHERE rolls < 12;`

In the main file, that handles the commands for the telegram-bot I have some function, for e.g:

```
async def show_rolls(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE, rolls):
    await update.message.reply_text(rolls)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = ApplicationBuilder().token(TOKEN).build()
    app.add_handler(CommandHandler('rolls', show_rolls))
```

Every time a user uses the `/rolls`
command the bot shows how many rolls they have (which are stored in the Database, they get 3 every day)

Tried the schedule module, in the database.py file:

```py
import schedule

schedule.every().day.at('15:00').do(add_rolls)
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
```

The `add_rolls` function just does the query I mentioned, it works as intended.

Entering the while loop stops everything, when the users sends a command the bot doesn't respond.

Also tried the following, using the telegram-bot module itself:

```py
async def add_roll_schedule(context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> None:
    roll1_time = datetime.time(
        hour=18, minute=0, tzinfo=pytz.timezone('America/Sao_Paulo'))
    context.job_queue.run_daily(add_rolls, roll1_time)
    
   job = context.job
   await context.bot.send_message(job.chat_id, text='Rolls Added')
```

But I can't find a way to call this command every time the bot is online, since is required to send the context.

Comment: where is the rest of the code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)...

Comment: @D.L Tried to give more info into the problem, let me know if you have any specific question.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution using the threading python module.

To be more efficient I will not show my exact functions, just a e.g:

```py
import schedule, time, threading

def hello():
    print('hello')

def check_schedule():
    while True:
         schedule.run_pending()
         time.sleep(1)

# Start a new thread only to check if there is any schedule pending.
threading.Thread(target=check_schedule).start() 

# Defining when the function is called
schedule.every().day.at('19:00').do(hello)
```

If anyone has a more efficient/healthy way to do this, let me know! :)

Answer (score 0):

The [`JobQueue`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.ext.jobqueue.html) is also available as [`Application.job_queue`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.ext.application.html#telegram.ext.Application.job_queue). So you can schedule jobs directly after defining the `app` in your example.

In general, I would advice not to mix threading and asyncio.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.

Comment: thank you for been so active in the `python-telegram-bot` community, just updated my code.